# Does each instance of an enclosing class have its own copy of an inner/nonstatic-nested class?

Tags: java, oop, instance, inner-classes

We say that nested classes are *members* of the enclosing class.

Does this mean that each instance of the enclosing class has its own copy of a(n) inner/nonstatic-nested *class*, just like each instance of a class has its own copy of a nonstatic/instance method?

---

**My question is Not a duplicate of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145887/must-inner-classes-have-a-reference-to-the-enclosed-class) linked in the banner above my question.**

That question discusses whether an inner class automatically keeps a reference to the enclosing class (even if the reference is never used).

My question is that since all instances of a class have their own copies of all *nonstatic member* fields(and methods? - I am not sure about methods) - opposed to static members  which have only one copy which is available to all instances of the class; and since we say that nested classes are *members* of enclosing classes, and then inner classes would become *nonstatic/instance-members* of the enclosing classes, right?

So can one conclude that each instance of the enclosing class has its copy of each inner class?

I don't even find the two questions to be similar, let alone duplicates. I am really genuinely wondering what part of my question is related to an inner class holding a reference to enclosing class.

My question has been answered perfectly precisely in the accepted answer.

Comment: why not simply try it out?

Comment: "just like each instance of a class has its own copy of a nonstatic/instance method?" but they don't.

Comment: An [single] enclosing class can have *multiple* inner classes: what might these multiplicities imply?

Comment: @Turing85 Try out exactly what? There are a number concepts mixed up in my mind and this question is crucial to them. Those questions and confusions arose trying something like this. If you can tell me what kind of program should I write, I'll tell why trying that out won't help me clarify my confusion.

Comment: @Downvoter: Can I know the reason for the downvote, so that I can improve in future?

Comment: @Solace you question shows insufficient research effort. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html - Oracle tutorials are usually (this being no exception) as simple as possible. FYI, if you get a downvote, it usually means "your asking the wrong question".

Comment: @Kayaman Are you sure? Because I read that somewhere. "but they don't" - that implies that there is only one copy of an instance-method, and it is available to all instances of the class, right? In that case, what is the ultimate difference between static and instance methods, except the syntactic differences?

Comment: @Solace the difference between a static and a nonstatic method is that a nonstatic method has a implicit parameter of the class'es type it is written in (i.e. realizing the acces through `this`). Each method is present only once.

Comment: @vaxquis You did not understand my question at all. The tutorial you linked to, I have read it multiple times. And I searched, none of the those questions answer my question. If you think its a dupe of dozens of those, can you give me a yes or no answer? Please understand that I am not talking about _objects_ of inner class, but the _class_ itself. No offence, but you seem to think that all questions about nested classes are the same, just like you seem to think that my question is same as asking whether inner classes hold reference to enclosing class.

Comment: @Solace what do you mean by "class"? `Class` object? Class definition descriptor? `.class` file? I didn't understand your question, because it's a lousy question - a) the answer *is* in the Oracle docs, b) if you don't understand how both Java's class system and inner classes work, no amount of handwaving will make you get it. The answer is "your question currently has little sense. Improve your question, you'll get an answer".

Comment: also, FWIW, the compiler generates *exactly one* `.class` file for *any* class - be it a regular one, inner one or even synthetic one. There's also just one definition of given class loaded into `javac`, and just one `Class` object created for each and every of them. Further reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3 (yes, that link IS present in the answer in the dupe link I've given to you)

Comment: @user2864740 that the enclosing class can have multiple inner classes; what else? I am asking whether every instance of the enclosing class has its own copy of the inner _class_ (not talking about _objects_ of inner class, but the inner class itself), just like every instance of the enclosing class (or any class for that matter) would have its own copies of all instance-fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a small example from the description you have given. Please correct me if I did not understand you correctly, but this is what I read out of your description.

```
public class Outer {
    class Inner {

    }

    public Inner inner = new Inner();

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Outer o1 = new Outer();
        Outer o2 = new Outer();

        System.out.println(o1.inner == o2.inner);
        System.out.println(o1.inner.getClass() == o2.inner.getClass());
    }

}
```

When you execute the program, you may see that the instances of `Inner` are not equal, but the classes of the inner instances are. Hopefully,  this answers your question.

Comment: From this I can conclude that the _inner-class_ for every instance of an enclosing class is always the same; but every instance of an enclosing class has its own copy of _every instance of its inner-class_ - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, and you were right when you said, "why not simply try it out" (that's why I upvoted the comment), but it simply didn't occur to me to check it like this. I have not yet learnt about reflection (getClass()).

Comment: @Solace this is not reflection. Reflection is explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: @Turing85 /agree about reflection. If we were to *do* something with the `Class` returned (e.g. enumerate its methods, load/unload it dynamically etc.) - that would probably be a reflective operation; yet just using `getClass()` and comparing the results is no more reflective than [`typeof`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeof)/RTTI; it's *introspection* instead of *reflection* actually.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that each instance of the enclosing class has its own copy of a(n) inner/nonstatic-nested class,

Each instance of the enclosing class may be referenced by zero or more instances of an inner class.

Each instance of an inner class has an implicit reference to exactly one instance of the enclosing class.

By the way, an *inner class* is a nested class that's not declared static. "Inner class" includes both anonymous and non-static nested classes.

Comment: @vaxquis - It was a valid criticism of my earlier looser language. An outer instance does not implicitly connect to an inner instance. Using the verb "has" to mean "is referenced by" is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @AndyThomas It *is* a stretch, true. Still, they are connected in the reference graph (GC etc.) implicitly, but of course I agree you can't simply get all the inner instances [without heavy VM magic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#IterateOverInstancesOfClass) or without some kind of explicit tracking.